# C - Sending struct array over pipe

Tags: c, arrays, struct, pipe

I'm trying to send an array of structs through a pipe. I have a struct:

```
typedef struct visitordata {
    char name[80];
    char email[80];
    int id;
    char reg_time[9];
}visitordata;
```

Then I do

```
//...
//ds is the number of struct entries to be stored
visitordata* V;
V = (visitordata*)malloc(ds * sizeof(visitordata));

pid_t child = fork();
if(child < 0) {
    perror("Fork error");
        exit(1);
    }
 else if (child > 0) { //parent process
    write(pipefd[1], &V, sizeof(V));
    close(pipefd[1]);
    fflush(NULL);
    pause();

    sleep(1);
    pause();
    kill(child,SIGTERM);                
    waitpid(child, &status, 0);
}
else { //child process
    visitordata* data;
    close(pipefd[1]);

    read(pipefd[0], &data, sizeof(data));
    close(pipefd[0]);
    flush(NULL);
    for (i = 0; i < ds; ++i) {
        printf("Received: %s\r\n", data[i].name);
    }

    kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
    pause();                
}
```

But then, if I have two rows for input, the Received part only prints out one row with the string "free" (which I think comed from the username on the server: `freeze@server:`) and then `Received:` without anything else. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Updated the code as per suggestions:

```
visitordata* V;
V = (visitordata*)malloc(ds * sizeof(visitordata));

pid_t child = fork();
if(child < 0) {
    perror("Fork error");
        exit(1);
    }
 else if (child > 0) { //parent process
    write(pipefd[1], V, ds * sizeof(V));
    close(pipefd[1]);
    fflush(NULL);
    pause();

    sleep(1);
    pause();
    kill(child,SIGTERM);                
    waitpid(child, &status, 0);
}
else { //child process
    visitordata* data;
    data = (visitordata*)malloc(ds * sizeof(visitordata));
    close(pipefd[1]);

    read(pipefd[0], data, ds * sizeof(data));
    close(pipefd[0]);
    flush(NULL);
    for (i = 0; i < ds; ++i) {
        printf("Received: %s\r\n", data[i].name);
    }

    kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
    pause();                
}
```

Now my output is like this:

```
Received: 0▒:▒0▒:▒ 
Received:
```

**EDIT 2**

Updated

```
read(pipefd[0], data, ds * sizeof(data));
```

and

```
write(pipefd[1], V, ds * sizeof(V));
```

to

```
read(pipefd[0], data, ds * sizeof(visitordata));
```

and

```
write(pipefd[1], V, ds * sizeof(visitordata));
```

Now my output is:

```
Received: 0Tɢ0Tɢ
Received:
```

Comment: You should not be using `sizeof` in your `write` and `read` calls. You are reading and writing the number of bytes in a pointer (e.g. 4 or 8) - you need to pass the actual length of the data.

Comment: Could you please explain?

Comment: I'll add an answer shortly.

Comment: You're not actually writing and reading the data in the array, you are writing and reading a *pointer to the data*. This works only as long as you allocate the memory ***and initialize it*** before you `fork` the child process.

Comment: @lte__: you haven't updated the code correctly, e.g. look at the calls to `write` and `read` and compare them with the fixed versions in my answer below.

Comment: Oh I see now! Updated again, I'll update the post

Comment: @PaulR I think I got it right this time, array still doesn't seem to go through though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing incorrect parameters to both `write` and `read`. You need to pass a pointer to the actual data, and the length of the data in bytes.

So:

```
write(pipefd[1], &V, sizeof(V));
```

should be:

```
write(pipefd[1], V, ds * sizeof(visitordata)); // note: 2 fixes here
```

and similarly:

```
read(pipefd[0], &data, sizeof(data));
```

should be:

```
read(pipefd[0], data, ds * sizeof(visitordata)); // note: 2 fixes here also
```

---

Also, as noted by [@Someprogrammerdude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude), you `data` pointer is not initialised (it's just a *wild pointer*). Change:

```
visitordata* data;
```

to:

```
visitordata* data = malloc(ds * sizeof(visitordata));
```

Comment: Ok, now I updated this, but it's still not working perfectly. I'll edit the question in a minute.

Comment: Oh shoot sorry, I'll fix it!

Answer (score 2):

`read()` and `write()` read and write **up to** the number of bytes requested.  Per the [POSIX standard for `write()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pwrite.html):

> The `write()` function **shall attempt to write** `nbyte` bytes from
>   the buffer pointed to by `buf` to the file associated with the open
>   file descriptor, `fildes`.
>
> ...
>
> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> Upon successful completion, these functions shall return the number of bytes actually written to the file associated with `fildes`. This number shall never be greater than `nbyte`. Otherwise, -1 shall be returned and errno set to indicate the error.

Your code never checks the results of write - you merely *hope* it works.
To ensure the *entire* requested number of bytes is written, you need something like this:

```
size_t bytesToWrite = ds * sizeof(visitordata);
size_t totalWritten = 0;

for ( ;; )
{
    ssize_t bytesWritten = write( pipefd[1], V + totalWritten,
        bytesToWrite - totalWritten );
    if ( bytesWritten <= 0 )
    {
        break;
    }

    totalWritten += bytesWritten;
}
```

You need to handle `read()` similarly.

Comment: My output is still memory junk :/

Comment: @lte__ Did you do the same on the `read()` side?  Are you running a debugger to see how many bytes actually get written and read?  You can also add debug output to your code using something like `fprintf( stderr, ...);` to find out what your code is actually doing.

Comment: Yes, I did it for the read side, too. I'll try to debug it somehow.

Comment: If I just send a string over the pipe, it works. Maybe I'll just iterate through it and send the strings...

Comment: @lte__ You *should* be able to send the entire array of structures.

Comment: Well, apparently I'm not :D

Comment: @lte__ That's what makes debugging, errr, *fun*.  Yeah, that's the word...

Answer (score -1):

This smells:

write(pipefd[1], &V, sizeof(V));

Maybe this is better:

write(pipefd[1], V, sizeof(V));

The receving part is also problematic. Where do allocate a buffer for it?
visitordata* data;